# unable-to-populate-view-or-view-model with EF6 and Knockout

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

This is a follow on from the question  [unable-to-populate-view-or-view-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678798/unable-to-populate-view-or-view-model)
working through a proof of concept for a SPA using our Company database data from a series of examples / articles [Using Web API 2 with Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/). This is my first attempt at a SPA

Unfortunately, when I run the project I get this, which is clearly wrong I have checked the SQL side and the data is there in the SQL view
[image: Example of Web page]

I can not see what my error is. Can anyone spot it please?

If I have understood the articles correctly I have set up the view, then the view model which calls a Get api to populate the Json view model. This then calls my server model based on EF6.

However there are no error messages from the SQL server and no build errors, so my guess is as I am testing this on and off the network and I am getting not error messages it feels Like I am not calling for a connection to the database correctly or else when I am off the network would the code should not find the database connection as the SQL server would not be there and return so sort of error?

I can post more of my code as requested.

Here is my view code

```
   @section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
}

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Requistions Approval</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Requistions</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: Requistions">
                    <li>
                        <strong><span data-bind="text: Requistion"></span></strong>
                        : <span data-bind="text: Line"></span>
                        : <span data-bind="text: ReqnValue"></span>
                        : <span data-bind="text: OrigName"></span>
                        : <span data-bind="text: LineReqnRaised"></span>
                        : <span data-bind="text: ReasonForReqn"></span>
                        : <span data-bind="text: GLDescription"></span>
                        <small><a href="#">Details</a></small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: error"><p data-bind="text: error"></p></div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here is my Controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Requestions_Api_POC.Models;

namespace Requestions_Api_POC.Controllers
{
    public class RequistionsForApprovalsController : ApiController
    {
        private Requestions_Api_POCContext db = new Requestions_Api_POCContext();

        // GET api/RequistionsForApprovals
        public IQueryable<RequistionHeaderDTO> GetRequistionsForApprovals()
        {
            var Requistions = from b in db.RequistionsForApprovals
                              select new RequistionHeaderDTO()
                              {
                                  ID = b.ID,
                                  Requisition = b.Requisition,
                                  ReqnValue = b.ReqnValue,
                                  ApprovedValue = b.ApprovedValue,
                                  OrigName = b.OrigName,
                                  Line = b.Line,
                                  LineReqnRaised = b.LineReqnRaised,
                                  DueDate = b.DueDate,
                                  ReasonForReqn = b.ReasonForReqn,
                                  Supplier = b.Supplier,
                                  GLDesc = b.GLDesc,
                                  CurrentHolder = b.CurrentHolder,
                                  CurName = b.CurName,
                                  CurEmail = b.CurName,
                                  HoldersRouteNum = b.HoldersRouteNum,
                                  DateActioned = b.DateActioned,
                                  DatabaseName = b.DatabaseName,
                                  AdUser = b.AdUser,
                                  ServerName = b.ServerName
                              };
            return Requistions;


        }
```

Here is my Data Transfer object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Requestions_Api_POC.Models
{
    public class RequistionHeaderDTO
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Requisition { get; set; }
        public decimal? ReqnValue { get; set; }
        public decimal? ApprovedValue { get; set; }
        public string OrigName { get; set; }
        public decimal Line { get; set; }

        public System.DateTime? LineReqnRaised { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public string ReasonForReqn { get; set; }
        public string Supplier { get; set; }
        public string GLDesc { get; set; }
        public string CurrentHolder { get; set; }
        public string CurName { get; set; }
        public string CurEmail { get; set; }
        public decimal? HoldersRouteNum { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateActioned { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        public string AdUser { get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit your previous question? You're basically asking the same things and only show a bit more code.

Comment: Sorry i did not realise if I edited it would "attract" answers. I thought you had to re ask

Comment: Hi i have post my code on my orginal question. Can I delete this question now? If so how?

Comment: That has been done as c#